# Ядро не реагирует на реальную клавиатуру

Tags: linux, клавиатура, ядро

Собираю Linux From Scratch. Ядро 5.15.56, amd64. Включил в ядре поддержку клавиатур, различных USB-протоколов. На виртуалке QEMU SeaBIOS все прекрасно работает. На реальном ПК - ОС не реагирует на клавиатуру. Не подскажете, что включить в ядре или как вообще разрешить клавиатуру? ПК - UEFI.

При включении дебага event-ов в ядре при нажатии на клавиатуру появляются только логи в dmesg, реального нажатия не происходит.

Comment: Смотреть, что там с поддержкой и фактическим наличием OHCI/UHCI/EHCI/xHCI.

Comment: Prokoshev, про HCI не в курсе, поизучаю. Но вообще не подскажете, что конкретно надо включить/выключить?